# jQuery - If statement, combine two IF's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate an input field with jQuery. I want to check if the `val();` of the field is more than 5, or if the value of the field is smaller than 2.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
$('#customamount').keyup(function() {
    $('.amount-field').text($(this).val());
    if($(this).val() > 5){
        $(this).addClass("error");
        $(this).prop("title","Whoops! Too high");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        $(this).attr("title","Good!");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');     
    }
    if($(this).val() < 2){
        $(this).addClass("error");
        $(this).prop("title","The minimum amount is 2.");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        $(this).attr("title","Good!.");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');     
    }
});
<input type="text" value="10" id="customamount">
```

Currently, it just adds the `.success` class to the input and the `title="Good!"`

How can I combine the above two IF statements?

Comment: It is very basic programming question

Comment: @nagarajub I'm new to programming in jQuery - thought I could get some help here, even though it's basic for the majority.

Comment: Hey, You have good reputation (782), solved many questions how come you miss this simple programming logic

Comment: Don't understand why people can't just answer simple questions rather than downvoting and being punks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using `else if`:

```
    if($(this).val() > 5){
        $(this).addClass("error");
        $(this).prop("title","Whoops! Too high");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');
    }
    else if($(this).val() < 2){
        $(this).addClass("error");
        $(this).prop("title","The minimum amount is 2.");
        $(this).tooltip('toggle');
    }else{

       $(this).removeClass("error").addClass("success");
       $(this).attr("title","Good!.");
       $(this).tooltip('toggle');      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up that function a lot by using and `else if`, a temporary variable for `$(this)`, method chaining, and moving re-used code out of the `if` statements:

```
$('#customamount').keyup(function() {
    var t = $(this); // Only convert `this` to a jQuery object once.
    $('.amount-field').text(t.val());

    if(t.val() > 5) {
        t.addClass("error")
         .prop("title","Whoops! Too high");
    } else if(t.val() < 2) {
        t.addClass("error")
         .prop("title","The minimum amount is 2.");
    } else {
        t.removeClass("error").addClass("success")
         .attr("title","Good!");
    }
    t.tooltip('toggle'); //Whatever the value of `t.val()`, this should be called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this = $(this); 
var val = $this.val();
if(val > 5) {
  // case for 5
  return;
}
if(val < 2) {
  // case for 2
  return;
}
// good case
```

Sidenote: cache your jquery calls. don't redo them. It's unnecessary work which hits performance if you do it a lot.

Also you should have a look at this:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Dont stress yourself with validation when there are simpler ways to get it done :)

Comment: Don't duplicate if statements like that. That makes it less maintainable.